# How do I name a query table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I do a very simple query selecting 2 columns out of the 5 columns in a table. How do I name the query table for future use?
Sorry for asking something that sounds so obvious but have looked for answer everywhere and could not find any.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Perhaps a [`View`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)? Or a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)?

Comment: Name it `the_2_out_of_5_columns_view_from_table_whatever`. Always go for the name, that best describes its content!

Answer (score 0):

A view would allow you to group columns from different tables so you can view that data all at once.
An example would be if you had a SALES view to report on
you would create the SALES VIEW by joining a Customer table so you can see who purchased the item, you would also include a Inventory, or Items table so you can see the details of the item purchase.

So next time you need to query which customer bought which item, you would just query against the view that would contain all the columns you need